# Behat test validation message

Tags: javascript, php, validation, behat

I have validation form  using JavaScript and I want to test the  validation message, because messages are in few languages.  However, Behat throws an  exception

> Could not open connection: Curl error thrown for http POST to
>
> http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session with params:
>   {"desiredCapabilities":{"tags":["vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32","PHP
>   7.0.1-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1"],"browser":"firefox","ignoreZoomSetting":false,"name":"Behat
>   feature suite","browserName":"firefox"}}
>
> Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)

```
Feature: Validator form contact
  In the contact form  to see a validator message

  @javascript
  Scenario: Message validation in English lang
    Given I am on "/"
    When I fill in "name" with "behat"
    And I fill in "email" with "example@example.com"
    And I fill in "phone" with "111222333"
    And I fill in "message" with "That test message, send via Behat."
    When I press "Send Message"
    Then  I wait for the suggestion box to appear
    Then  I should see "Your message has been sent."
```

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext {

```
public function __construct() {
}

/**
 * @Then /^I wait for the suggestion box to appear$/
 */
public function iWaitForTheSuggestionBoxToAppear() {
   $this->getSession->wait(5000, false);
}
```

behat.yml:

```
default:
extensions:
  Behat\MinkExtension:
    goutte: ~
    base_url: 'http://localhost.dev/'
    javascript_session: selenium2
    browser_name: firefox
    selenium2: ~
```

How should I testing that  case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick question, have you started your WebDriver on port 4444?

Because I replicated the error that you got simply by switching off my chromedriver.

```
     [Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  Exception has been thrown in "beforeScenario" hook, defined in FeatureContext::windowSizeChange()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  Could not open connection: Curl error thrown for http POST to http://127.0.0.1:9515/session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","version":"8","platform":"ANY","browserVersion":"8","browser":"firefox","name":"Behat test","deviceOrientation":"portrait","deviceType":"tablet","selenium-version":"2.31.0","max-duration":300}}  
  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9515: Connection refused

  [WebDriver\Exception\CurlExec]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  Curl error thrown for http POST to http://127.0.0.1:9515/session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","version":"8","platform":"ANY","browserVersion":"8","browser":"firefox","name":"Behat test","deviceOrientation":"portrait","deviceType":"tablet","selenium-version":"2.31.0","max-duration":300}}  
  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9515: Connection refused
```

For selenium webdriver: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<versionNumber>.jar -port 4444`

For chromedriver: `chromedriver --port=4444`

For operadriver: `operadriver --port=4444`

And also, is this segment in your FeatureContext.php?

```
default:
 extensions:
  Behat\MinkExtension:
    goutte: ~
    base_url: 'http://localhost.dev/'
    javascript_session: selenium2
    browser_name: firefox
    selenium2: ~
```

Because if it is, it is in the wrong place, and needs to be in your behat.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default of chrome driver for latest selenium, and it would support only chrome browser.

put in behat.yml

```
default:
  autoload:
    '': %paths.base%/features/bootstrap
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: your url
      default_session: selenium2
      files_path: features/Resources
      show_cmd: 'open %s'
      selenium2:
        browser: chrome
        wd_host: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

Use your selenium last version should be 52.3

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of options to fix this problem, but for me it was the chromedriver version.
I finally managed to fix it by downloading the correct version of chromedriver from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ because the one I had was not okay.